# How do I parse a matrix from file in Haskell?

Tags: file, haskell, matrix, handle

I'm new in Haskell.
I trying to parse a text file with two matrices. The insides of a text file:

```
    m n
    a11 a12 ...
    a21 a22 ...
    ...
    b11 b12 ...
    b21 b22 ...
    ...
```

where m is number of rows of the 1st matrix, n is number of rows of the 2nd matrix.
For instance:

```
        3 2
        1 2 3
        4 5 6
        7 8 9
        1 2
        3 4
```

I know, looks stupid, but I have a task parse a text file with 2 matrices and I only came up with it.
 
There is the code:

```
readLine :: Read a => Handle -> IO [a]
readLine = fmap (map read . words) . hGetLine

parse :: Handle -> IO (Matrix a, Matrix a)
parse = do
    [m, n] <- readLine
    xss1    <- replicateM m readLine
    xss2    <- replicateM n readLine
    return (fromLists xss1, fromLists xss2)

main = do
  [input, output] <- getArgs
  h <- openFile input ReadMode
  (m1, m2) <- parse h
  print $ mult m1 m2
```

There is a log from console:

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Matrix           ( lab.matrix.hs, interpreted )

lab.matrix.hs:156:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO [a0]' with actual type `[t0]'
    In the pattern: [m, n]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: [m, n] <- readLine
    In the expression:
      do { [m, n] <- readLine;
           xss1 <- replicateM m readLine;
           xss2 <- replicateM n readLine;
           return (fromLists xss1, fromLists xss2) }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Most likely, there are still a few bugs.
Help me please, I'm exhausted already...

Comment: You need to do something with the `Handle` in `parse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a `Handle` as an argument to every call of `readLine`, so `parse` could look like this:

```
parse h = do
    [m, n] <- readLine h
    xss1 <- replicateM n $ readLine h
    xss2 <- replicateM m $ readLine h
    return (fromLists xss1, fromLists xss2)
```

Another note - it's probably safer to check the number of arguments returned by getArgs, rather than just assuming there will be two. For example:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        [input, output] -> do
             h <- openFile input ReadMode
             (m1, m2) <- parse h
             hClose h
             print $ show mult m1 m2
        _ -> putStrLn "expected two arguments"
```

Comment: Covering all cases is safer, yes, but you should still simply pattern match on the list instead of calling `length` followed by indexing.

Comment: Done. It's not that your way is wrong, but this is more idiomatic Haskell and `length` traverses the whole list and then indexing traverses it again. For a short `args` list that's fine and sometimes you really need indexing, but it generally shouldn't be the first thing you consider.